# Sorting by a field in another index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indexes, one that maintains product data and another that maintains inventory. Due to the sheer size of the volume of updates and the data set, I cannot have these merged into a single index. Below is a rough idea of the problem I have at hand.

Product Documents will be maintained on a product index ‘product’. The sample documents could look like below

```
{
                "id":1,
                "name":"P1",
                "desc":"P1 product"
},
{
                "id":2,
                "name":"P2",
                "desc":"P2 product"
}
```

Inventory for products will be maintained on a separate index named ‘inventory’ and records would look like below

```
{
                "id":1,
                "available":10
},
{
                "id":2,
                " available ":5
}
```

I would like to retrieve products that match a query criteria, but sorted by the value in the second index -  by available field

**Query by keyword: *, sort by available, but return only the Product Index data**

Can someone please provide a context of how I can achieve this using elasticsearch